# C# - Why implement two version of Current when realizing IEnumerable Interface?

Tags: c#

I assume the following sample gives a best practice that we should follow when we implement the IEnumerable interface.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext

Here is the question:

1. Why should we provide two version of **Current** method?
2. When the version ONE (object IEnumerator.Current) is used?
3. When the version TWO (public Person Current ) is used?
4. How to use PeopleEnum in the foreach statement. // updated

```
public class PeopleEnum : IEnumerator
{
    public Person[] _people;

    // Enumerators are positioned before the first element
    // until the first MoveNext() call.
    int position = -1;

    public PeopleEnum(Person[] list)
    {
        _people = list;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < _people.Length);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    // explicit interface implementation
    object IEnumerator.Current /// **version ONE**
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public Person Current     /// **version TWO**
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _people[position];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason is that this code example was derived from an example class implementing `IEnumerator<T>` - if the example class `PeopleEnum` implemented `IEnumerator<T>` this approach would be required:  `IEnumerator<T>` inherits  `IEnumerator` so you have to implement *both* interfaces when implementing  `IEnumerator<T>`.

The implementation of the non-generic `IEnumerator`  requires `Current` to return object - the strongly typed  `IEnumerator<T>` on the other hand requires Current to return an instance of type `T` - using explicit and direct interface implementation is the only way to fulfill both requirements.

Comment: I just found that you in fact gave the answer I need. -- thank you

Answer (score 7):

The `IEnumerator.Current` is an *explicit* interface implementation.

You can only use it if you cast the iterator to an `IEnumerator` (which is what the framework does with `foreach`). In other cases, the second version will be used.

You will see that it returns `object` and actually *uses* the other implementation which returns a `Person`.

The second implementation is not required per se by the interface, but is there as a convenience and in order to return the expected type instead of `object`.

Comment: Although all of this is correct, you inference is that the cast to IEnumerator is rare; it isn't. IEnumerable requires a GetEnumerator() method that returns an object of type IEnumerator, cast as such. GetEnumerator() is, in turn, used by pretty much any built-in code that uses IEnumerables, such as foreach and most of Linq.

Answer (score 4):

Long-form implementation of IEnumerator is no longer necessary:

```
public class PeopleEnum : IEnumerable
{
    public Person[] _people;

    public PeopleEnum(Person[] list)
    {
        _people = list;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Person person in _people)
            yield return person;
    }
}
```

And to further bring it into the 21st century, don't use the non-generic IEnumerable:

```
public class PeopleEnum : IEnumerable<Person>
{
    public Person[] _people;

    public PeopleEnum(Person[] list)
    {
        _people = list;
    }

    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Person person in _people)
            yield return person;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is there for convenience, eg. using the PeopleEnum.Current in a typesafe way in a while(p.MoveNext()) loop, not explicitly doing a foreach enumeration.

But the only thing you need to do is implement the interface, you could do it implicitly if you wish, however is there a reason for it? If I wanted to use MovePrevious on the class? Would it be cool if I should cast(unbox) the object to Person?

If you think the class could be extended with more manipulation methods the Person Current is a cool thing.

Answer (score 1):

Version two isnt part of the interface. You have to satisfy the interface requirements.